# Can't install on my laptop

Tags: system-installation

I have an existing Windows 10 installation and a free partition with 600 GB in which I would like to install Elementary.

I have created a USB ISO for Elemetary OS Juno. I firstly used Rufus, but I have also tried with Universal USB Installer.

I have set nomodeset in GRUB and also acpi=off and the combination of both. No matter what I do, no matter what pen drive I use... installation always freezes, and it happens either in the "Updates and other software" window when I click continue or after choosing "Some other", which leads me to a window in which it tries to show me the partition table (which never shows up).

I don't know what to do, I have tried everything I've seen, and the laptop is an Asus from past year with Intel Core i7 and NVIDIA GeForce. If I boot from the USB, no problem, but if I try to install, it always freezes.

I understand that I might be having problems with NVIDIA drivers (for what I have read), but I also understand that using nomodeset and acpi=off should skip the problem. BTW, when I set acpi=off, I got a black screen and the installation doesn't even start.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem was that the system was constantly giving "PCI bus error". I caught that when I hit the power button to restart. I googled the error and arrived to this answer, whose solution worked for me: [PCI bus error severity corrected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected)

Just set pci=nomsi in GRUB and I could install seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

on my case, i can't even try Juno, I got a black screen for 3 seconds and my laptop reboot..
I tried with different kernel parameter nomodeset, nouveau.modeset=0, acpi=off i915.modeset=0, same issue

system config : i7 6700HQ, nvidia GTX950m, Samsung SM951 128GB M.2 PCI-e ACHI SSD

I stuck with Loki until I can fix the issue

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to comment on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) from the asker. | >> [Help Center](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help) <<